# Why does Android Activity move button after changing background?

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity with the following image button:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/nextPage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:contentDescription="@string/nextPageString"
    android:alignParentRight="True"
    android:alignParentBottom="True"
    android:onClick="NextPage" />
```

My Button appears in the bottom right corner of the screen as I would expect.

When I click the button I change the background with the following code:

```
public void NextPage(View view){
    Resources res = this.getResources();
    Drawable d = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.nextBackgroundImage);
    view.setBackground(d);
}
```

After I click the button the first time it displays my new background exactly as I want, however, it moves the image button to the center of the screen.  Not sure why.  I would like it to stay in the bottom right corner.

Comment: I guess `nextBackgroundImage` is not of same size as your `ImageButton`. that is why it maintain the aspect ratio of the Image. and display it in the center.

Comment: Try setting android:layout_width and android:layout_height to some defined values for a test

Comment: How big is the image? While this won't solve your problem you can use `view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nextBackgroundImage);` and your code above sets the width twice but not the height...

Comment: That did it!  Thank you Alex for the suggestion on the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several of the comments here have noted, the SIZE of your background image is likely why you're button is "moving." With `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to wrap, the size will change if the content of the view (including its background) changes.

+1 for Alex, try setting a specific size there just to TEST and see what happens (200dp width x 80dp height, for example).